# Observation, observation

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

You have been chosen to participate in a selection process for a secret underground group. To make sure you're worthy, they test you with a series of devious puzzles. However, one in particular has you stumped...

The challenge you receive is as follows:

> People aren't very good at observing things. We hope you are better.
> To solve this challenge, you will need to inspect the contents of the link below:
> [https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKGpe.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2plV.png/)
> We look forward to your success.
> - The Underground Group

The solution is obvious once found, and requires no special skills to uncover.
But, of course, you need to keep your eyes and mind open...

Comment: Well, the displayed link is different from the actual link. But it tells me "The image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available." Or is this a red herring?

Comment: @Glorfindel It's not a red herring; look closer. However, I don't know what the clue means...

Comment: Wow, another great puzzle!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not done yet, I think, but:

> Using the fill option in paint, this came out:
> [image]
> Keep looking!

Also:

> The displayed and actual link are different. Following the displayed link shows:
> [image]
> Again, filling it in in paint shows:
> [image]
> So, is the answer 404? Or is it something to do with either imgur or PSE's 404 page?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Ah, so the lack of a dot on the i of imgur.com was a red herring?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is

> 404

How it's hidden...

> The linked image is described as https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKGpe.png
>  but actually points to https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2plV.png/.
>  The image actually linked to contains very faint text that reads Keep Looking.
>  The file XKGpe.png contains to real solution.
>  Using a flood fill or colour replacement tool will reveal the text.

Comment: This is correct. However the other answer is faster so I will accept that one. But you still get a +1 :D